# Transforming coordinates according to Point of View.

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems

Imagine I have two cameras (A and B) in the same axis and looking at
the same white wall with a black dot. Both cameras see the black dot.
I'd like to know how to proceed in order to derive the black dot's
coordinates seen from point of view B.

What is known:

- Black dot coordinates seen from A;
- Camera B position in relation to camera A;
- Distance (in meters) from the black dot to the cameras (depth).

Comment: If you are seeking a practical reply then What do you mean by coordinates and is the distance you know the distance between A and the Black dot?

Comment: Coordinates may be x,y pixel coordinates in an image captured by the camera, and the distance is the length of a line segment connected to the camera and the black dot.

Comment: You should put this question in Stack Overflow. I think that's where the question belongs. Add a comment here if you do and I'll try and reply. For both sites there is too little information given.